# How do I configure a .NET Core 3 application to use a SPA and Swagger UI?

Tags: .net-core, nswag

## Problem

When I attempt to load the SwaggerUI when visiting `localhost:5001/swagger` I receive an error in the SwaggerUI that alerts me of the following:

`Fetch error undefined /swagger/v1/swagger.json`

It is also interesting to note that my .NET application is raising an error as well when visiting the SwaggerUI.

```
System.OverflowException: Value was either too large or too small for a Decimal.
   at System.Number.ThrowOverflowException(TypeCode type)
   at System.Decimal.DecCalc.VarDecFromR8(Double input, DecCalc& result)
   at System.Decimal.op_Explicit(Double value)
   at NJsonSchema.Generation.JsonSchemaGenerator.ApplyRangeAttribute(JsonSchema schema, IEnumerable`1 parentAttributes)
   at NJsonSchema.Generation.JsonSchemaGenerator.ApplyDataAnnotations(JsonSchema schema, JsonTypeDescription typeDescription)
   at NJsonSchema.Generation.JsonSchemaGenerator.<>c__DisplayClass37_1.<LoadPropertyOrField>b__0(JsonSchemaProperty propertySchema, JsonSchema typeS
chema)
   at NJsonSchema.Generation.JsonSchemaGenerator.GenerateWithReferenceAndNullability[TSchemaType](ContextualType contextualType, Boolean isNullable,
 JsonSchemaResolver schemaResolver, Action`2 transformation)
   at NSwag.Generation.OpenApiSchemaGenerator.GenerateWithReferenceAndNullability[TSchemaType](ContextualType contextualType, Boolean isNullable, Js
onSchemaResolver schemaResolver, Action`2 transformation)
   at NJsonSchema.Generation.JsonSchemaGenerator.LoadPropertyOrField(JsonProperty jsonProperty, ContextualMemberInfo memberInfo, Type parentType, Js
onSchema parentSchema, JsonSchemaResolver schemaResolver)
   at NJsonSchema.Generation.JsonSchemaGenerator.GenerateProperties(Type type, JsonSchema schema, JsonSchemaResolver schemaResolver)
   at NJsonSchema.Generation.JsonSchemaGenerator.GenerateObject(JsonSchema schema, JsonTypeDescription typeDescription, JsonSchemaResolver schemaRes
olver)
   at NSwag.Generation.OpenApiSchemaGenerator.GenerateObject(JsonSchema schema, JsonTypeDescription typeDescription, JsonSchemaResolver schemaResolv
er)
   at NJsonSchema.Generation.JsonSchemaGenerator.Generate[TSchemaType](TSchemaType schema, ContextualType contextualType, JsonSchemaResolver schemaR
esolver)
   at NJsonSchema.Generation.JsonSchemaGenerator.Generate[TSchemaType](ContextualType contextualType, JsonSchemaResolver schemaResolver)
   at NJsonSchema.Generation.JsonSchemaGenerator.GenerateWithReferenceAndNullability[TSchemaType](ContextualType contextualType, Boolean isNullable,
 JsonSchemaResolver schemaResolver, Action`2 transformation)
   at NSwag.Generation.OpenApiSchemaGenerator.GenerateWithReferenceAndNullability[TSchemaType](ContextualType contextualType, Boolean isNullable, Js
onSchemaResolver schemaResolver, Action`2 transformation)
   at NJsonSchema.Generation.JsonSchemaGenerator.GenerateArray[TSchemaType](TSchemaType schema, JsonTypeDescription typeDescription, JsonSchemaResol
ver schemaResolver)
   at NJsonSchema.Generation.JsonSchemaGenerator.Generate[TSchemaType](TSchemaType schema, ContextualType contextualType, JsonSchemaResolver schemaR
esolver)
   at NJsonSchema.Generation.JsonSchemaGenerator.Generate[TSchemaType](ContextualType contextualType, JsonSchemaResolver schemaResolver)
   at NJsonSchema.Generation.JsonSchemaGenerator.GenerateWithReferenceAndNullability[TSchemaType](ContextualType contextualType, Boolean isNullable,
 JsonSchemaResolver schemaResolver, Action`2 transformation)
   at NSwag.Generation.OpenApiSchemaGenerator.GenerateWithReferenceAndNullability[TSchemaType](ContextualType contextualType, Boolean isNullable, Js
onSchemaResolver schemaResolver, Action`2 transformation)
   at NSwag.Generation.AspNetCore.Processors.OperationResponseProcessor.Process(OperationProcessorContext operationProcessorContext)
   at NSwag.Generation.AspNetCore.AspNetCoreOpenApiDocumentGenerator.RunOperationProcessors(OpenApiDocument document, ApiDescription apiDescription,
 Type controllerType, MethodInfo methodInfo, OpenApiOperationDescription operationDescription, List`1 allOperations, OpenApiDocumentGenerator swagge
rGenerator, OpenApiSchemaResolver schemaResolver)
   at NSwag.Generation.AspNetCore.AspNetCoreOpenApiDocumentGenerator.AddOperationDescriptionsToDocument(OpenApiDocument document, Type controllerTyp
e, List`1 operations, OpenApiDocumentGenerator swaggerGenerator, OpenApiSchemaResolver schemaResolver)
   at NSwag.Generation.AspNetCore.AspNetCoreOpenApiDocumentGenerator.GenerateForControllers(OpenApiDocument document, IGrouping`2[] apiGroups, OpenA
piSchemaResolver schemaResolver)
   at NSwag.Generation.AspNetCore.AspNetCoreOpenApiDocumentGenerator.GenerateAsync(ApiDescriptionGroupCollection apiDescriptionGroups)
   at NSwag.Generation.AspNetCore.AspNetCoreOpenApiDocumentGenerator.GenerateAsync(Object serviceProvider)
   at NSwag.AspNetCore.OpenApiDocumentProvider.GenerateAsync(String documentName)
   at NSwag.AspNetCore.Middlewares.OpenApiDocumentMiddleware.GenerateDocumentAsync(HttpContext context)
   at NSwag.AspNetCore.Middlewares.OpenApiDocumentMiddleware.GetDocumentAsync(HttpContext context)
   at NSwag.AspNetCore.Middlewares.OpenApiDocumentMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at IdentityServer4.Hosting.IdentityServerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context, IEndpointRouter router, IUserSession session, IEventService event
s)
   at IdentityServer4.Hosting.MutualTlsTokenEndpointMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context, IAuthenticationSchemeProvider schemes)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at IdentityServer4.Hosting.BaseUrlMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore.MigrationsEndPointMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore.DatabaseErrorPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore.DatabaseErrorPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

## What I Want To Happen

I want to be able to serve my SwaggerUI which documents the API that serves my React.js application.

## How I Reached This Problem

I created a new .NET Core 3 using the 'with React.js' template typically found in JetBrains Rider or Visual Studio and installed/configured the NSwag Nuget. The front-end is primarily, if not entirely, served by the React.js application while the .NET web application simply serves as an API.

*Startup.cs*

```
using System.Text.Json.Serialization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.ReactDevelopmentServer;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using FitnessApplication.Data;
using FitnessApplication.Models;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;

namespace FitnessApplication
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlite(
                    Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

            services.AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();

            services.AddIdentityServer()
                .AddApiAuthorization<ApplicationUser, ApplicationDbContext>();

            services.AddAuthentication()
                .AddIdentityServerJwt();

            services.AddControllersWithViews();
            services.AddRazorPages();

            services.AddControllers().AddJsonOptions(opt =>
            {
                opt.JsonSerializerOptions.Converters.Add(new JsonStringEnumConverter());
            });

            // In production, the React files will be served from this directory
            services.AddSpaStaticFiles(configuration => { configuration.RootPath = "ClientApp/build"; });

            services.AddSwaggerDocument();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseSpaStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseIdentityServer();
            app.UseAuthorization();
            
            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
                endpoints.MapRazorPages();
            });
            
            app.UseOpenApi();
            app.UseSwaggerUi3();
            
            app.UseSpa(spa =>
            {
                spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";

                if (env.IsDevelopment())
                {
                    spa.UseReactDevelopmentServer(npmScript: "start");
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

## Attempts to Remediate the Problem

I first tried to remediate this by placing the methods calls to `app.UseOpenApi();` and `app.UseSwaggerUi3();` below my call to `app.UseSpa();` thinking that there was some sort of logical error in when these methods are being called but that only made matters worse making my SwaggerUI completely inaccessible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading the error raised by my .NET application when visiting `localhost:5001/swagger` it became immediately obvious that there was something wrong in either my models or controllers that prevented the Swagger specification from being generated. Turns out I was attempting to use a float on a model attribute validation when the model attribute was a double.

*UserStrengthMovement.cs*

```
[Required]
[Range(0, float.MaxValue)]
[DefaultValue(0.0)]
public double WeightKilograms { get; set; }
```

The forementioned code block needs to be changed to:

```
[Required]
[Range(0, double.MaxValue)]
[DefaultValue(0.0)]
public double WeightKilograms { get; set; }
```